# Setting a value that has parameters

Tags: java, while-loop

I am looking for a way to set the value `index.totalNumCitations` to the value I set in that while loop. I set the value to `1` initially so the for loop would execute at least once. I tried obtaining the value before the for loop and that also wasn't working. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be very appreciative.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < index.totalNumCitations; i++) {


       while (inputInteger > 50 || inputInteger < 0) {
           inputInteger = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
           index.Index(inputInteger);
    }
```

This is the method used in the while loop

```
public void Index(int totalNumCit) {
    if (totalNumCit <= 50 && totalNumCit > 0) {
        this.totalNumCitations = totalNumCit;
        citationIndex = new Citation[totalNumCit];
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: Please enter a number between 0 and 50.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is the `index` variable?

Comment: And what are you asking about really?

Comment: It is a class. I am not sure if that is what you were referring to.

Comment: I want to know why I'm not able to use that value assigned in the while loop.

Comment: You want a `for-loop` with a dynamic end-bound???

Comment: I actually want to know if there is a way I can set that value requiring those parameters without using a while loop but also keep inquiring for the value until the criteria is met.

Comment: I would advise this: post you question as a user requirement (what does the user wants/needs to do). Your code makes no sense at the moment (sorry)

Comment: can you post more of your code.

Answer (score 1):

When asking a question, try to describe more generally what you're trying to do.
People might be able to come up with a better solution.

But for this case i would suggest you put the while-loop before the for-loop. Because if you don't change the value of inputInteger elsewhere in the for-loop, the while-loop will only run in the first cycle of the for-loop.

```
while (inputInteger > 50 || inputInteger < 0) {
           inputInteger = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
           index.Index(inputInteger);
}

for (int i = 0; i < index.totalNumCitations; i++) {

    //whatever you want to do

}
```